# Java Add Just MouseClicked Listener

Tags: java, events, awt, mouselistener

I would like to have a component listen JUST to mouseClicked events and all other things(mouseEntered, mousePressed, etc.) to be sent to the lower component in the z-level. I don't want to do dispachEvent() because then it is still the same event(mousepos) that gets sent. Thanks!

Comment: *"I would like to have a.."*  ..question?  What *is* your question?

Comment: How can I make all non-mouseClicked events go to the next component in the z-level?